# $\int_{\partial R} \, f(z)\,dz=0$ if $z_0 \notin R$ for a rectangle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z_0 \in \Bbb C$, $A\subset \Bbb C$ and $f:A \setminus \{z_0\} \to \Bbb C$ be holomorphic and continuous in $G$. Suppose furthermore that $R \subset A $ is a rectangle and $z_0 \notin R$. Then $$\int_{\partial R} \, f(z)\,dz=0$$

I guess this should follow from the cauchy theorem but I don't see the relation. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The intuitive thinking is, the point is outside the rectangle so if you take an open set U that covers the rectangle but not the point. Then f is holomorphic in U, and since $\partial R$ is a closed loop, because of Cauchy it integrates 0.
Thus, you need to prove there is such set: since $z_0\not\in R$ and R is closed and $\lbrace z_0\rbrace$ is compact $\implies d(z_0,R)>0$ it follows naturally that you can get an open set U.

Comment: Thank you for your good answer. If I can continue my question, what is in the case that $z_0 \in R$, so in the inside. We should get again that the integral is 0, not?

Comment: not necessarily, for example 1/z is continuous and holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$\ $\lbrace0\rbrace$ but the integral on any rectangle that contains 0 is $2\pi i$. If it were continuous on A, and holomorphic on $A$ \ $\lbrace z_0\rbrace$ then yes, it would integrate 0. BTW, do note that in your problem you have A and G I assumed G is A\z_0 an open set, if thats not the case then you can't really take that U without knowing $R\subset A^\circ$